# Problem with Scrolling a list

Tags: java, android

I've one application which is containing some item in List. I've successfully installed this into my device (Samsung Galaxy SII). In my emulator i can view the items by scrolling that. But, in my device it seems black shaded on the item. How can i reduce that? Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
android:cacheColorHint="00000000" // set to transparent
```

in `ListView` tag in XML layout